# Attach unique identifier to object click event with multiple events

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making a minimap for my game. When you click on the map, it expands into a larger map. I've added a click handler to the minimap element.

```
$("#minimap").click(function(){  
    expand larger map
```

I've also made tooltips which tell the user to click on the minimap. When the user clicks on the minimap, it removes the tooltip. This event handler binding is happening within the Tooltip class:

```
$("#minimap").on("click", function () {
    $(this).unbind("click");
    removeChild(the tooltip object);
```

I don't want the tooltip action to continue firing each time I click to expand the map, so I unbind it. Unfortunately, this unbinds the action to expand the minimap defined elsewhere.

How can I attach some sort of unique ID to tell `$("#minimap")` to only unbind the click event associated with the tooltip?

Comment: look at the tooltip plugin how to remove it... is it the jquery ui tooltip

Comment: @arun no, it's an event handler to manipulate canvas tooltips ive made. I'm only using jquery to allow the canvas tooltips to respond to dom actions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things you can do:

1. Use `one` instead of `on`, as [Drakes suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30837638/157247).
2. Keep a reference to the function and unbind just that one function later:

   ```
   function tooltipClickHandler() {
       $(this).off("click", tooltipClickHandler);
       removeChild(the tooltip object);
   }
   $("#minimap").on("click", tooltipClickHandler);
   ```
3. Use an [event namespace](http://api.jquery.com/on/#event-names), which lets you uniquely specify just *your* click handler without having to remember the function reference:

   ```
   $("#minimap").on("click.tooltiphandler", function () {
       $(this).off("click.tooltiphandler");
       removeChild(the tooltip object);
   });
   ```

---

Side note: I've used `off` rather than `unbind` above, because you've used `on` to set up the handler and `off` is the "preferred" way as of jQuery 1.7.

Comment: Nice writeup. I like your additional solutions.

Answer (score 2):

Use [.one()](http://api.jquery.com/one/) to only bind it once and then forget about it

> Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element per event type ([ref](http://api.jquery.com/one/)).

```
$("#minimap").one("click", function () {
    removeChild(the tooltip object);
```